# "This is like..." events based on standard deviation

Tags: references, standard-deviation

I'm trying to communicate, in lay terms, how rare a 10, 11, 12 etc. standard deviation move is assuming a normal distribution.  I'd like to say something like, "a 10 standard deviation move is like randomly firing a gun and hitting the moon."  Is there a nice table of such events than can be used for an illustrative discussion?

Answer (score 1):

Your wording is a bit strange, but I think what you are looking for is events that have the same probability as drawing an observation from a normal distribution that is 10 or more standard deviations away from the mean. So let's see first what the probability of this is (using R):

```
> pnorm(10, lower.tail=F)
[1] 7.619853e-24
```

So roughly $7.6/1000000000000000000000000$.

Here is one example that most people should easily understand. Suppose you are rolling a 6-sided die (yes, here comes the statistician again with those damn dice). Then the chances of rolling the same number 31 times in a row is about of that same magnitude:

```
> 6 * (1/6)^31
[1] 4.523374e-24
```

Note that we have to multiply `(1/6)^31` by `6` since there are 6 different possibilities of rolling the same number 31 times in a row.

Answer (score 0):

With these probabilities, if you consider the [number of people that have ever been born](http://www.prb.org/Publications/Articles/2002/HowManyPeopleHaveEverLivedonEarth.aspx) (as of mid 2011) of $107,602,707,791$, the odds of a $6.717\sigma$ event would be that one person in the history of Earth died in a way that no one else ever had.

According to [this](http://www.aleph.se/andart/archives/2009/09/ten_sigma_numerics_and_finance.html) article, a $10\sigma$ event has a probability of $1.523970\times10^{-23}$. (The article also discusses the difficulties in even performing the calculation to determine the probability of the event.)

To compare that event, it might be helpful to think of something that is even on that scale.  According to [one estimate](http://www.npr.org/sections/krulwich/2012/09/17/161096233/which-is-greater-the-number-of-sand-grains-on-earth-or-stars-in-the-sky),

> the Earth has roughly (and we're speaking very roughly here) $7.5 \times 10^{18}$ grains of sand

The [star survey from 2003](http://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/2003/07/25/910295.htm) reported that there are approximately $70\times10^{21}$ stars visible from Earth.

Thankfully, there are larger numbers by looking small.  Within the molecular weight in grams, there are (approximately) $6.022140857 \times 10^{23}$

So, roughly speaking, the odds of a ten sigma event would be the same as finding *exactly* four isotopes of gold within \$7,616.23 worth of pure gold (at \$1,202.70 per Troy Ounce).

The problem is, the numbers are so huge, people have a hard time comprehending the enormity of it.  Any hyperbole could be used to try and put the experience in non-mathematical terms, but moving from ridiculous to absurd and ensuring appropriate increases in likelihood would be difficult.